# save element position on canvas after orientation change

Tags: android, canvas, screen-rotation

i am using a canvas based on [android-multitouch-controller](https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/), 
im am trying to keep imageElement on canvas on same place after orientation change

the arrow represent an element based on image,
i was able to rotate it by saving the original orientation and add a delta angle on orientation change.

but i am having problem with the ordinations, because the 0,0 is changing place, based on the orientation

[image]